# MS Power Automate Error when trying to input Site Address

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I'm trying to utilize MS Power Automate to automatically create a New List Item on my Sharepoint 2019 List from responses in MS Forms. I'm using the template "**Record form responses in SharePoint**" and am stuck in the **Create Item** step.

The Sharepoint Subsite URL and List Name produces an error:
[image]

> The dynamic operation request to API 'sharepointonline' operation
> 'GetTable' failed with status code 'Unauthorized'. This may indicate
> invalid input parameters. Error response: { "message": "Access token
> not found clientRequestId: 4162a960-da54-470d-90e7-fae4a4c404cb",
> "fromPolicy": true }

I've also noticed some unusual characteristics on the URL format which is https://share.domain.com/teams/x/x/x/Subsite

Which is quite different from the common Sharepoint URL formats:
https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename

I would like to know how to get past this error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can’t use that connector with SharePoint on prem. Is that what you’re trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I see, is it as easy as changing the connector or is there a different solution to achieve what I'm trying to do with an on-prem sharepoint?

Comment: Have a read of this and see if it helps?  https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/support-for-sharepoint-on-premises/